# 2 local user profiles, same settings, different result. Hello?

Tags: windows-7, profiles

Here's a super doozy I can't figure out.

Windows 7 Home

I connect to work using Citrix desktop. I access a secure html site using my domain credentials, which triggers a download and starts Citrix

This worked normally up until this morning. I lost network connectivity when my router started behaving badly. After regaining the internet, I attempted to login, but was told my credentials were invalid and locked out. I tried chrome, Firefox and ie. Same result. I assumed i mistyped and got myself locked out.

Call to the network admin told me my account was fine.

Retried, still no joy. On a hunch, I switched to my wife's old profile on my computer since she used to work on it, and she uses the same Citrix desktop receiver.

Signed in as her, got to the desktop, opened ie, hit the same site, entered my credentials... Success! Authenticated and download initiated. Retried in Firefox and chrome, same story. No issues when logged into my wife's profile.

Logged out, logged back in as me, tried again, invalid credentials/locked out message.

So, I know my account isn't locked out. Admin confirmed, and I can access it through my wife's. It's not a browser issue, because all 3 work on my wife's windows profile.
Network adapter settings, firewall settings, router settings are all global so if it doesn't affect my wife's local profile, it shouldn't affect mine.

Why would my profile be failing the authentication process outrigh?. I'm convinced it's not even sending the credentials through, just failing outright. But I don't know why?

I'm going to attempt DNS flush tonight and if that fails, try an earlier system restore point. But I'll take any suggestions under advisement while i use my wife's local account as a work around.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So dumb.

Wife's local URL was slightly different. Her bookmark was simply:

www.[companyname].com/remote

which resolved to a much longer URL starting with:

assist.[companyname].com/Auth/**XenApp**/....

and i stupidly just typed in:

assist.[companyname].com

which resolved to

assist.[companyname].com/Auth/**Xen[Company]**/....

and thats all she wrote.